# How can a file inside a pod be copied to the outside?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have an audit pod, which has logic to generate a report file. Currently, this file is present in the pod itself. I have only one pod having only one replica.

I know, I can run `kubectl cp` to copy those files from my pod. This command has to be executed on the Kubernetes node itself, but the task is to copy the file from the pod itself due to many restrictions.

I cannot use a Persistent Volume due to restrictions. I checked the Kubernetes API, but couldn't find anything by which I can do a copy.

Is there another way to copy that file out of the pod?

Comment: Have you look into Kubernetes's volume system to store the data outside the pod, somewhere it can survive the pod being deleted and recreated?  Or pushing the data into a database, or a message queue, or cloud storage somewhere?

Comment: I am not supposed to use the kubernetes volumes. My application is a light weight process and it not advisable to use a db. For message ques, again there should be a receiver to put the contents to a storage. I don't have any cloud storage. I have just control over my pod and my application. I thought K8s APIs are great way to deal with this problem, but no luck

Comment: @subrat Could you please explain the restrictions that you mention in the question?

Comment: @OhHiMark sorry for the Delay. 1) pod names are not accessible to my user, and they are not expected to (do a cp/exec) on the pod. 2) I cannot use PVC, because I use helm, my service is of type deployment and my container is running in different user, I cannot take a PV as an input to my PVC(as it mounts it as root, even though securityContext.fsGroup is provided). Dynamic PV is not useful because with every restart the PV gets deleted.

Comment: @subrat That a lot of restrictions.. Please tell me, are you able to use sidecar containers in your use case?

Comment: @OhHiMark No, My application is a simple audit application and it does not expose any ports. that's why I don't have to use a sidecar. Although I have the flexibility to use, istio service mesh.

Comment: currently, I have used the dyamic pv and used the annotations."helm.sh/resource-policy": keep. But again, here the issue is with the namespace, every time I delete it my pvc get's deleted.

Comment: @subrat Sorry for the late response. Do you still need help with this?

Comment: @OhHiMark Thanks for your support!! And follow ups, as I have Mentioned, I had to use PVCs only and explicitly mention the user to not to delete the namespace. :(

Answer (score 1):

This is a community wiki answer posted to sum up the whole scenario and for better visibility. Feel free to edit and expand on it.

Taking under consideration all the mentioned restrictions:

- not supposed to use the Kubernetes volumes
- no cloud storage
- pod names not accessible to your user
- no sidecar containers

the only workaround for your use case is the one you currently use:

> the dynamic PV with the annotations."helm.sh/resource-policy": keep

> use PVCs and explicitly mention the user to not to delete the
> namespace

If any one has a better idea. Feel free to contribute.